# Is there "infinite" universal model selection ? and Structural Risk Minimization

Tags: machine-learning, model-selection, regularization

I  ask these because I come up with an idea :

> If I have *infinite* and *universal* model set, then there must exist model that *totally* fits my data and *no* parameter for the model so the complexity is zero.

(e.g. a delta distribution on my data or the training data points itself if supervised learning)
After model selection ( using regularizer or cross-validation) , it is of course the best model.

That's paradoxical .

Is it related to `Structural Risk Minimization` principle? Why `Vapnik` has it to be *hierarchy* structure in model set?  Is that only then can we exclude the above weird case?
Is infinite model selection not exist in reality? Is any theory discuss it?

Comment: "*If I have infinite model set, and there must exist model that totally fits my data*" --- well, actually, it's pretty easy to come up with infinite classes of models that can still fail to match your data. So the simple assertion "if it's infinite it must fit my data exactly" isn't necessarily the case. You probably need to slightly modify your statement there.

Comment: Yes. The statement have been modified .